# R - bigrquery::bq_auth() function does not work - I can not reauthenticate to connect with BigQuery

Tags: r, google-bigquery, dbi, bigrquery

First things first:

- Operating System: Windows 10
- R version: 4.2.2

**Story**
I am trying to import data from Google BigQuery to R. I am using `bigrquery` package. However any operations after creating DBI connection results in the same way - I get error message saying `Access Denied`.

Here is the code:

```
# libs
library(bigrquery)
library(DBI)

# connection
con <- dbConnect(
  bigrquery::bigquery(),
  project = "project-nmae",
  dataset = "dataset",
  billing = "project-for_billing"
)

dbListTables(con)
```

Error I get:

> Error in `signal_reason()`:
> ! Access Denied: Dataset x:y: Permission bigquery.tables.list denied on >dataset x:y (or it may not exist). [accessDenied]

**Problem**
So OK. I have got multiple google accounts so I would like to force bigrquery to reauthenticate to make sure I am using proper one.

So as described in the [documentation](https://bigrquery.r-dbi.org/reference/bq_auth.html) I am calling `bq_auth(email=NA)` and I expect that R should open browser with authentication page but nothing happens. No errors and totally no action.

I have also manually removed all tokens stored by gargle package. When I check tokens using `gargle::gargle_oauth_sitrep()` I get info that 0 tokens have been found. However it has not helped.

**Question**
Does anyone know how to force bigrquery to reauthenticate and why `bq_auth(email = NA)` doesn't work?

Comment: Hi @Adrian Gasinski, Can you provide the full query which you are using to authenticate using bq_auth(email=NA)? You can refer to [link1](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/user-managed/use-r-bigquery) and [link2](https://github.com/r-dbi/bigrquery) for more information.

Comment: having this exact issue as well on bigquery 1.4.1 and M1 mac

Comment: `bigrquery` has trouble with authentication quite often. I don't really know why.